# I'm trying to create a saved search in Netsuite that shows only items whose 1st time it was ever received was today

Tags: filter, netsuite, summary

I want to filter my search so it shows only items whose 1st item receipt is today. So, I can create an alert for whenever we receive a new product in which is a lot of different parts so doing it sku by sku would be too time consuming.

I created a search and summarized it on minimum date but I can't figure out how to just show me items whose 1st time being received into our system is today.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps in creating the Item Saved Search:

- Navigate to List> Searches> Saved Searches > New
- Select **Search Type = Item**
- Navigate to Criteria tab > Standard subtab > Filter column and add the following:
- **Transaction Fields… > Type- is Item Receipt**
- **Type - is any of Assembly/Bill of Materials, Inventory Item**
- **Transaction Fields… > Date and Summary Type: Minimum**

4. **Navigate to Results tab > Sort By: Name**
5. Navigate to Results tab > Columns subtab > Field column and add the following fields:

- **Name and Summary Type: Group**
- **Transaction Fields… > Date and Summary Type: Minimum**

7. Hit Save & Run button

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Create your saved search on items
- On the results tab

  - add Transaction Date. Set its summary type to Minimum
  - Group by item name. You can sum and min/max other columns as needed
- On the criteria tab:

  - add transaction type is 'Item Receipt'
  - click the Summary subtab.

    - add a criteria for minimum transaction date is today.

When you run this you'll see items whose first receipt is today.

Comment: Great! If you mark the answer as accepted that will help others make use of it.